# How can i write unittest for android fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, robolectric

I am creating the application that contain the fragment, for that I want to write unit test for that using the

> **Robolectric**

code as per below

```
public class PlaybackFragment extends Fragment {

private CustomView customView;
private MyViewModel MyViewModel;

public static PlaybackFragment newInstance() {
    return new PlaybackFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initViews(view);
    initControllers();
    subscribeViewModel();
    loadData();
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    // init customView
}

private void initControllers() {
    // click events
}

private void subscribeViewModel() {
    //observer
}

private void loadData() {
    //load data for fragment
}
```

}

So, how can I write unit test for that.

Comment: what exactly do you want to test? that your methods are being run ?

Comment: I am tried to test all click events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the robolectric dependency in your **build.gradle** file:

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0'
```

**Step 1**-Create your Activity Test Class in test package.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ActivityTest {

    private ActivityTest  activity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(ActivityTest.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldHaveWelcomeFragment() {
        assertNotNull(activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.welcome_fragment));
    }
}
```

**Step 2**-Create Fragment Test Class to check if fragment is null or not

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class WelcomeFragmentTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldNotBeNull() {
        WelcomeFragment fragment = WelcomeFragment.newInstance();
        startFragment(fragment);
        assertNotNull(fragment);
    }
}
```

Comment: can i write only for fragment class?

Comment: Yes you can.Just use the Welcome Fragment Test

Comment: why u create ActivityTest class?

Comment: So that i can test my Activity classes as well along with fragment class

Comment: If I write unit test for fragment that count as a UI Test(View)?

Comment: Depends what test you are writing.If you checking some logic then it won't count as UI Test but if you are checking if fragment is null or if button is clicked or what action is performed then that is UI Test.